# Perfect secrecy definition

Tags: cryptography

My question is we know that perfect secrecy is achieved with the messages in uniform distribution. But what will it be if the message distribution is not uniform ? How will we then define perfect secrecy?

Comment: Can you quote the definition here? That would help the discussion.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If K is the distribution and ENC. is the algorithm, ENC. is perfectly secret if for any m,M Pr[M=m|Enc(K,M) = c] = Pr[M=m]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

To give a convincing answer, it's best to discuss a few possible ways of defining security. The correct definition is not obvious and historically took lots of research and some iteration to approach it.

Most people who think about it agree that a "one-time pad" is perfectly secure in a very strong sense. One-time pad is a very old technique, it was known before WWII and such.

The idea is like this: You are a spy, and I am your spymaster handler. I want to send you abroad to collect secrets and send them back to me. In order that we can communicate, I first create an entire book full of random numbers. (Some machine mechanically flips a coin and prints zero or one, lets say.) I have a copy, and you have a copy, and no one else does.

When you want to send me `k` bytes of message, you take `k` bytes from the book, and XOR them with your bytes. (Then you advance your bookmark by `k` bytes.) When I receive `k` bytes from you, I XOR them with the next `k` bytes in the book, and advance my bookmark.

Even if the enemy intercepts all of your messages, if we consider how they would look as a function of the (random) bits in the book, the messages the adversary recieves are distributed as independent coin flips. Indeed for any fixed message that you send, `message xor book` is perfectly random if the `book` is random.

So, this scheme is perfectly secure -- the ciphertext is statistically independent of the plaintext, so the adversary can learn nothing about your messages.

The problem with this is that you must exchange as many bytes privately before hand as you will exchange publicly. When you are doing e.g. credit card sales online, you cannot assume that there is a private exchange of key material beforehand. So it's important to be able to reduce the amount of key material needed.

On the other hand, if you reduce the key material to less than `k` bytes for a `k` byte message, then provably you will not achieve this level of security. The cipher text distribution will have to be different for different messages -- even you can show that there is large statistical distance between them as the number of bytes gets small.

In modern cryptography, the usual way to relax the definition is to try to restrict attention to *computationally bounded* adversaries.

One way of formalizing statistical distance of two distributions, `D1` and `D2`, is to say that the distance is the maximum over all test functions `T : { strings } -> { 0, 1 }` of the difference in expectations `E_{x ~ D_1} [ T(x) ]` versus `E_{x ~ D_2} [ T(x) ]`.

Then, we can modify the definition by focusing only on test functions `T` which are *efficiently computable*, say, in polynomial time, or subexponential time, or something. (Usually that something is the "security parameter".)

If the statistical distance of `D1` and `D2` is small for *computationally bounded* adversaries, we sometimes say, `D1` and `D2` are *indistinguishable*.

Then, we can say that a cryptographic protocol is secure if, for any fixed message `m`, over the probability in the random seed / key, the distribution of the cipher text is indistinguishable from the uniform distribution.

It is widely believed, under reasonable cryptographic assumptions, that this can be achieved even for keys which are much shorter than the message. But this cannot be proved rigorously to be true without proving P != NP and many other difficult things. We would need more rigorous constructions of pseudorandom generators, for example, even in the case that the generator is more expensive to compute than the adversary, which is still not known.

Note that in this formalism, it doesn't matter what the message distribution is. Whether you are taking your messages, and then compressing them, and then encrypting them, or encrypting plain english text, the goal is that for *every* fixed message string, the randomness in the seed / key is enoguh to produce a distribution that fools your adversary.

There are other ways you could formalize security, but I think this is a decent way to do it.

---

Key point:

If the security condition holds for any *fixed* message, then it also holds for any fixed *distribution* of messages, by an averaging argument. That makes this definition very robust.